# Guice - Default binding definition

Tags: java, binding, guice

Is there a way to declare default binding in Guice 3.0 ?

Here is an example of what I expected :

```
//Constructor for Class Impl1
@Inject
public Impl1 (@One IMyOwn own)
{
   ...
}

//Constructor for Class Impl2
@Inject
public Impl2 (@Two IMyOwn own)
{
   ...
}
```

---

```
//Declare a default binding
bind(IMyOwn.class).to(DefaultMyOwn.class);
```

---

```
//Then, if I want to bind a custom implementation for @Two
bind(IMyOwn.class).annotatedWith(Two.class).to(TwoMyOwn.class);
```

Actually, this example can't works because I must declare a binding for all annotation (@One, @Two).

Are there solutions to do that with Guice ?
Thanks.

Comment: Did I have to use ToConstructorBindings ? [link](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ToConstructorBindings)

Comment: Regarding `toConstructor` binding: This is intended for cases where you cannot annotate the constructor with `@Inject`. Since you can, this is a non-issue for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guice tries to check as much of your configuration (aka. Binding) as possible. This also means, that Guice cannot tell whether a missing binding for `@One` is an error or should map to some default case.

If you are interested in the details, lookup the [BindingResolution](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/BindingResolution) sequence in Guice. Since step 4 and step 6 deal with binding annotation and step 6 explicitly forbids default, I think you are out of luck.

> .6. If the dependency has a binding annotation, give up. Guice will not create default bindings for annotated dependencies.

So the best you can do is to provide Guice with a hint, that `@One` should map to the default like this:

```
bind(IMyOwn.class).annotatedWith(One.class).to(IMyOwn.class);
```

So you do not need to state the concrete default class `DefaultMyOwn` multiple times.

Comment: It will be a bit dirty, BTW if it's the only way.. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use the @Named binding.

From [Guice Reference on Github:](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations#named)

Guice comes with a built-in binding annotation @Named that uses a string:

```
public class RealBillingService implements BillingService {
  @Inject
  public RealBillingService(@Named("Checkout") CreditCardProcessor processor) {
    ...
  }
```

To bind a specific name, use Names.named() to create an instance to pass to annotatedWith:

```
bind(CreditCardProcessor.class)
    .annotatedWith(Names.named("Checkout"))
    .to(CheckoutCreditCardProcessor.class);
```

So in your case,

```
//Constructor for Class Impl1
@Inject
public Impl1 (@Named("One") IMyOwn own)
{
   ...
}

//Constructor for Class Impl2
@Inject
public Impl2 (@Named("Two") IMyOwn own)
{
   ...
}
```

and your module will look like:

```
public class MyOwnModule extends AbstractModule {
  @Override 
  protected void configure() {
    bind(IMyOwn.class)
        .annotatedWith(Names.named("One"))
        .to(DefaultMyOwn.class);

    bind(IMyOwn.class)
        .annotatedWith(Names.named("Two"))
        .to(TwoMyOwn.class);
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case, couldn't you just bind the implementations? bin(Impl1.class).to(DefaultMyOwn.class)?

Comment: This is the correct way of implementing what OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

With Guice 4.X there is [Optional Binder](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.1/javadoc/com/google/inject/multibindings/OptionalBinder.html).

```
public class FrameworkModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    OptionalBinder.newOptionalBinder(binder(), Renamer.class);
  }
}

public class FrameworkModule extends AbstractModule {
  protected void configure() {
    OptionalBinder.newOptionalBinder(
               binder(),
               Key.get(String.class, LookupUrl.class))
                  .setDefault().toInstance(DEFAULT_LOOKUP_URL);
  }
}
```

In Guice 3.0 you may be able to exploit the automatic binding of the default constructor.

> 11. Use a single @Inject or public no-arguments constructor.

But this has constraints, as your default constructor needs to be of the same concrete class so derivation may become cumbersome.